# NSIS loading an NPAPI plugin

Tags: nsis

i have a NPAPI plugin !

How do i register the dll with an NSIS installer ? I tried this and it the compiler gives errors:

```
 # define the name of the installer
 outfile "simple installer.exe"

 RegDLL plugin.dll

 sectionEnd
```

The error is :

Error: command RegDLL not valid outside Section or Function
Error in script "C:\Program Files\NSIS\test01.nsi" on line 4 -- aborting creation process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegDLL is for DLL's that export the DllRegisterServer function. It is usually used by COM DLL's.

You can register a plugin with firefox by using the [NSIS registry functions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2):

```
!define pluginid "@example.com/myplugin"
Outfile "setup.exe"
InstallDir "$programfiles\myplugin"

Page Instfiles

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "myplugin.dll"

WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\${pluginid}" "Path" "$InstDir\myplugin.dll"
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\${pluginid}" "ProductName" "my plugin"
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\${pluginid}" "Description" "my useless plugin"
;Add Vendor,Version etc...
SectionEnd
```

..but if your NPAPI plugin actually has a DllRegisterServer export, you could use RegDLL...